# Как сделать такой update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос, но он не правильный

```
UPDATE
    info_users iu
INNER JOIN bets b ON
    iu.user_id = b.user
SET
    iu.balans = b.summa
```

Точнее правильный, но не работает на 100%... в таблица `bets`:

```
summa
user
id_match
id_team
```

нужно выбрать всех пользователей из таблице `bets`, у которых `id_match = 3` и `id_team = 4`, и сделать `update iu.balsn` на `b.summa`.

Структура info_users:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура bets:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для правильного ответа на вопрос необходимо знать структуру обеих таблиц и правила уникальности строк. соотносятся ли записи в таблицах одна к одному и если нет, то в какой из таблиц их больше. А может просто добавить `where id_match = 3 and id_team = 4`

Comment: Изменил в теме.

Comment: про уникальность вы так ничего не сказали, а это основное в данном вопросе, потому что невозможно выполнить апдейт одной строки на данные нескольких строк (если заранее не сгруппировать). По структуре приведенной таблицы не ясно уникальный там user_id или нет. И так же не ясно уникально ли поле user в таблице bets

Comment: user_id не уникален. щас скрин сделаю таблицы info_users

Comment: Этот update запрос изменят поле только у одного пользователя, а нужно... сделать так, выбрать все строки(т.е. все поля user/пользователи) из таблицы bets у которых id_match = 3 и id_team = 4 и сделать update в таблице info_users поля balans у этих пользователей, которые в таблице bets

Comment: Все равно не ясно что с уникальностью. я так понял в обоих полях поле не уникально. Предположим, в bets есть 5 записей с id_match=3 и id_team=4 и при этом у 3х из них user_id=20, а у 2х равен 30, суммы во всех записях разные. При этом в таблице info_users есть по 3 записи с каждым из этих пользователей. И что на что в таком случае менять, какую из сумм в баланс какой из целевых записей писать и как из отличать, если user_id у них одинаков, а других критериев сравнения нет

Comment: Так-ссс... я вас чутка вначале не понял, поля user, user_id уникальны, они одинаковы. Приведу вам такой пример.. в таблицу bets записываются ставки на команды, к примеру есть user = 3, ставит на команду_1(id команды равен 3, т.е. id_team=3), id матча этой игры равен 4, т.е. id_match, summa = 100, и есть еще один user = 4, тоже ставит на команду_1, туже сумму, и тот же id матча. в таблице info_users есть две записи с user_id = 3 и user_id 4. К примеру команда_1 выигрывает. И мне вот нужно сделать запрос, который изменит у этих пользователей их баланс, т.е. поле balans

Comment: Тогда возвращаемся к моему первому комменту, добавление `where id_match = 3 and id_team = 4` к запросу должно быть достаточно. (но структура таблиц вводит в заблуждение. если в info_users по каждому user_id только одна запись, то зачем в таблице собственный автоинкрементный id ?)

Comment: А вот... с этим что делать? INNER JOIN bets b ON
    iu.user_id = b.user

Comment: А что с ним не так, вроде у вас как раз задача сопоставить записи по id пользователя, так что оставить в покое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Заменяет `iu.balans` на `b.summa` у кого `b.id_match = 3` и `b.id_team = 4`

```
UPDATE info_users AS iu, bets AS b SET iu.balans = b.summa WHERE b.id_match = 3 AND b.id_team = 4 AND iu.user_id = b.user
```

2.Добавляет `b.summa` на `iu.balans` у кого `b.id_match = 3` и `b.id_team = 4`

```
UPDATE info_users AS iu, bets AS b SET iu.balans = iu.balans+b.summa WHERE b.id_match = 3 AND b.id_team = 4 AND iu.user_id = b.user
```

3.Если вам нужно только одна пользователь просто замените `iu.user_id = b.user` например на `iu.user_id = 1`